# Efficient way to Store Huge Number of Large Arrays of Integers in Database

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

I need to store an array of integers of length about 1000 against an integer ID and string name. The number of such tuples is almost 160000.

I will pick one array and calculate the root mean square deviation (RMSD) elementwise with all others and store an (ID1,ID2,RMSD) tuple in another table.

Could you please suggest the best way to do this? I am currently using MySQL for other datatables in the same project but if necessary I will switch.

Comment: Is the RMSD calculation going to be done in the database or by an external script? If it will happen externally, and this is the only use for that array, I wonder if it would work to store it as a binary blob?

Comment: @LindsayWinkler , I need it for an web service where user will request with the string name and i'll calculate RMSD of the array with requested name to all other arrays and reply the 10-50 names with minimum RMSD. once stored array values for a name will rarely updated , new arrays will be added occasionally.

Comment: Will that calculation be done in SQL using some built in or user defined function? Or will some external logic compute the RMSD values at that time? If the array is going to be extracted into some other code and the computations done there, you could just store binary data that the database doesn't have to understand or manipulate?

Comment: @LindsayWinkler, Thank you for your suggestion. I'll just calculate RMSD of 2 array, that is,sum=0; for i=0 to n-1 sum+=(arr1(i)-arr2(i))^2; RMSD=sqrt(sum);  I think if this is done in sql , calculation may be faster , or I may just retrieve array and calculate RMSD in server script. Thank you again for your suggestion. I'll try this. If there is any better way to do this plz guide me. I am developing a tool for my bioinformatics research project, so there is chance of need for more complex calculation in future. So, doing calculation in server script may be better than doing in sql.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to store the arrays in a `BINARY` or a `BLOB` type column. Given that the base type of your arrays is an integer, you could step through four bytes at a time to extract values at each index.

If I understand the context correctly, the arrays must all be of the same fixed length, so a `BINARY` type column would be the most efficient, if it offers sufficient space to hold your arrays. You don't have to worry about database normalisation here, because your array is an atomic unit in this context (again, assuming I'm understanding the problem correctly).

If you did have a requirement to access only part of each array, then this may not be the most practical way to store the data.

The secondary consideration is whether to compute the RMSD value in the database itself, or in some external language on the server. As you've mentioned in your comments, this will be most efficient to do in the database. It sounds like queries are going to be fairly expensive anyway, though, and the execution time may not be a primary concern: simplicity of coding in another language may be more desirable. Also depending on the cost of computing the RMSD value relative to the cost of round-tripping a query to the database, it may not even make that much of a difference?

Alternatively, as you've alluded to in your question, using Postgres could be worth considering, because of its more expressive `PL/pgSQL` language.

Incidentally, if you want to search around for more information on good approaches, searching for `database` and `time series` would probably be fruitful. Your data is not necessarily time series data, but many of the same considerations would apply.

Comment: Thank you. This suggestion seems attractive to me. I will try it and discuss with you about the performance then.